# What does Expected Reliability of a Circuit Mean?

Tags: reliability

I am a computer Science student, and I have to write a program that models the expected reliability of a circuit given a circuit diagram. The issue is that I have no idea what that means, and my research has only come up with things that are very technical.

So can anyone give me a basic idea of what this means?

Comment: Is the question asking about microelectronic component lifetimes, valid digital logic output delay, or distribution grid scheduled maintenance?

Comment: There's MTBF (useless for most things with software), the "bathtub failure curve", etc...

Comment: It depends on how you classify failure. For example, say it's a power supply; would it have failed if the output got a bit noisier because the electrolytic capacitors had dropped in value slightly? Or would it have to be a catastrophic failure?

Comment: Could you post one of your circuit diagrams? That would also be helpful. A "circuit" is a very vague reference.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way of thinking:

Each component has a failure rate. It can be measured in MTBF ([mean time between failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures)) (as @Nick T said) or [Failure Rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate). [Reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28engineering%29) is a number which states the probability that a component would still being working after an amount of time. In general for eletronic components it follows an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). You can use it to calculate the probability of a component still being functional after a given time.

For a circuit with no security systems (back-ups, redundant circuitry, etc) the overall reliability is the product of each reliability.

If you have a backup circuit, for example two redundant capacitors on the power supply, the probability that the capacitor bank is still working is the sum of the two probabilities.